# Display the list view of the Select component in a grid format (row of 3)

Tags: css, reactjs

In my react Dropdown component, when it is selected, the dropdown is in list view, 1 item per row, however I need to adjust it to be in a grid of 3 items per row.

Code:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown'

<Dropdown
  options={companyOptions}
  onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}
  value={this.state.selectedCompanyTemp}
  placeholder='---'
  filter
  className='filterbutton-company'
  filterPlaceholder='Search company'
/>
```

Reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE | Based on Primereact library:**

Since, you are using `primereact` library:

Try this line of code in your CSS file: Make sure to use this code after the library code is loaded. And in case you require to use `!important`, do that.

```
.p-dropdown-panel .p-dropdown-items {
    padding: 0.75rem 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Adjust the width of select field div as per your requirement. Debug your code in Browser Development window and play around.
[image]

Comment: I have mentioned which library is the Dropdown imported from. primereact.

Comment: @SikandarMalik Peace! I have updated the code for you based on the library you are using.
You need to debug and see which other changes you required (take inspiration from the screenshot that I have shared) Hope this helps

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you @ImranRafiqRather

Comment: You are welcome :) @SikandarMalik